# Computed `by` clause in data.table

Tags: r, data.table

A `by` clause can be a list of expressions which are used to compute the grouping columns. It can also be an expression that evaluates to a character vector of column names, if it's wrapped in `eval(…)`. But what if you want to decide programatically which and how many grouping variables are present, and also not all of those grouping variables are preexisting columns? You'd think it'd be doable with `eval`, `quote`, or `bquote`, but I can't figure it out.

As a simple but contrived example, suppose you want to write a function that works like this:

```
f = function(x)
  {d = as.data.table(mtcars)
   if (x)
       d[, by = .(mycyl = cyl + 1, myv = vs + 1),
           mean(wt)]
   else
       d[, by = .(mycyl = cyl + 1),
           mean(wt)]}
```

but looks like this:

```
f = function(x)
  {d = as.data.table(mtcars)
   d[, by = c(.(mycyl = cyl + 1), (if (x) .(myv = vs + 1) else NULL)),
       mean(wt)]}
```

How could this be accomplished? As written, the second version produces `Error in .(mycyl = cyl + 1) : could not find function "."`. If `.` is replaced with `list`, it produces `Error in eval(bysub, parent.frame(), parent.frame()) : object 'cyl' not found`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `quote` (`substitute` works as well):

```
f = function(x) {
    d = as.data.table(mtcars)
    byexpr <- quote(c(.(mycyl = cyl + 1), (if (x) .(myv = vs + 1) else NULL)))
    d[, mean(wt), by=eval(byexpr)]
}

f(TRUE)
#   mycyl myv       V1
#1:     7   1 2.755000
#2:     5   2 2.300300
#3:     7   2 3.388750
#4:     9   1 3.999214
#5:     5   1 2.140000

f(FALSE)
#   mycyl       V1
#1:     7 3.117143
#2:     5 2.285727
#3:     9 3.999214
```

check:

```
f0 = function(x) {
    d = as.data.table(mtcars)
    if (x)
        d[, by = .(mycyl = cyl + 1, myv = vs + 1),
            mean(wt)]
    else
        d[, by = .(mycyl = cyl + 1),
            mean(wt)]
}

f0(TRUE)
#   mycyl myv       V1
#1:     7   1 2.755000
#2:     5   2 2.300300
#3:     7   2 3.388750
#4:     9   1 3.999214
#5:     5   1 2.140000

f0(FALSE)
#   mycyl       V1
#1:     7 3.117143
#2:     5 2.285727
#3:     9 3.999214
```

Answer (score 1):

You were close actually. Use `list` instead of `.`

```
library(data.table)

d = as.data.table(mtcars)

d[, mean(wt), by = .(mycyl = cyl + 1, myv = vs + 1),]
#>    mycyl myv       V1
#> 1:     7   1 2.755000
#> 2:     5   2 2.300300
#> 3:     7   2 3.388750
#> 4:     9   1 3.999214
#> 5:     5   1 2.140000
d[, mean(wt), by = .(mycyl = cyl + 1)]
#>    mycyl       V1
#> 1:     7 3.117143
#> 2:     5 2.285727
#> 3:     9 3.999214

x = FALSE
d[, mean(wt), by = if(x) list(mycyl = cyl + 1) else list(mycyl = cyl + 1, myv = vs + 1)]
#>    mycyl myv       V1
#> 1:     7   1 2.755000
#> 2:     5   2 2.300300
#> 3:     7   2 3.388750
#> 4:     9   1 3.999214
#> 5:     5   1 2.140000

x = TRUE
d[, mean(wt), by = if(x) list(mycyl = cyl + 1) else list(mycyl = cyl + 1, myv = vs + 1)]
#>    mycyl       V1
#> 1:     7 3.117143
#> 2:     5 2.285727
#> 3:     9 3.999214
```

Comment: This seems to only work if the `if` is at the top level of `by`.  `by = c(list(mycyl = cyl + 1), (if (x) list(myv = vs + 1) else NULL)` gives the error mentioned above.

Comment: Yes, it is because of more or less obvious reason of lazy evaluation order.